# calculate the number of an algorithm with number of steps 6n^3+4n-20 and also calculate c and n0?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o, polynomials

I know that time complexity will be O(n^3). But how can I calculate c and n0 couldn't understand.
That's how I tried

```
6n^3+4n-20<=c.n^3
=>6+4/n^2-20/n^3 <= c
if n0=1 then c is -10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve

```
6 n³ + 4n - 20 < c n³
```

for all `n > N` (where `N` is also unknown).

Obviously, `c = 6` will not work. Let us try with `c = 7`. The inequation reduces to

```
n³ - 4 n + 20 > 0.
```

Now we see that `n³ > 4 n` as of `n > 2`, so a solution is `c = 7`, `N = 2`.

---

In fact, `N = 0` also works, but it is not necesssary to find a tight bound.

[image]